# Recommended rare items to upgrade in Kanai's Cube

Tags: diablo-iii

I am looking for `The Furnace`, the `Wand of Woh` the `Orb of Infinite Depth` and `In-geom`.
I heard the best way to get these items is to upgrade rare items in Kanai's cube.

But which rare items should I buy at the blacksmith that have the highest probability to turn into the items I am looking for?

Is there a list with more legendary items and their recommended rare counterpart?

Comment: For the furnace you would need to upgrade a Two-Handed Mace, for the wand of woh you would need to upgrade a wand, ect. It doesn't matter which Two-Handed Mace, aslong as it is that, you'll get a random chance of getting a furnace.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you use "Hope of Cain" recipe to upgrade a rare item to a legendary, the game creates a random item of **type** and **level** that the rare item was. Hence, to get The Furnace, you need to be upgrading a Rare Two-handed Mace (you can either find one, or craft a Sovereign Persuader at the Blacksmith).

When the game chooses which legendary to drop, it uses *weights* that determine how rare or common each legendary is. For example, here are all the Legendary two-handed maces and their weights:

- Arthef's Spark of Life - **100**
- Crushbane - **100**
- Schaefer's Hammer - **100**
- *Skywarden - 100 - does not drop for Wizard*
- Sledge of Athskeleng - **100**
- The Furnace - **25**
- Wrath of the Bone King - **50**

Hence, every time you roll for a legendary 2H Mace as a Wizard, you have 25/475 = 5.26% chance to get The Furnace, 50/475 = 10.53% chance to get a Wrath of the Bone King, and 100/475 = 21.05% chance to get each of four other maces.

You can check [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cM-s4e66ql2zsrkfkfKXmvVJ4zmngzxdzVLk9gvLvT8/htmlview?sle=true) for a table of all weights and drop chances for 2.4.2. In further versions, searching for "*diablo 3 legendary drop rates* " should get you there.

Comment: +1 for weight, not a lot of people know about the chance of specific legendaries based on weight.

Comment: If you play multiplayer, asking people in your party for the Furnace or In-geom if they already have one is also a very good way to get those.

Comment: Also, you can get a Rare Two-Handed Mace at Kadala

Comment: @Alex Correction: not "if they already have one", but "if it drops for them in the current game". Legendaries are only tradable to players who were in the game at the moment the item dropped.